# ms-access 2007 form datetime control : if control length smaller than the size of the value it shows ###

Tags: forms, date, size, controls, ms-access-2007

using ms-access 2007, when i want in a form to view a datetime field, it shows ##### if **the control size is smaller** than **the length value of the datetime field**

- If i increase the size of the control, it shows the value
- If i select the field, it shows the value too

My objectives are:

- I would like to show the content even if i don't see everything in once
- I don't want to format the value because i want the full date and time, and i will scroll inside the field to view details

It was working in ms-access 2000, but in 2007, i can't figure how to do it

Some ideas on how to deal with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't behave like this. You can either

- increase the width of the control (the best solution)
- specify a shorter Format for the date
- reduce the font size

An odd approach would be to add a label which obscures some of the date-control, but such that you can still see part of the date in the background.

You might consider using an event such as `Focus` to change the `Format` of the control, but this won't work as the Format only applies when you move away from the control.

You could, I suppose, use two controls; one for display and one for editing.